# System of three equations with 4 variables

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I am trying to solve this system of three equations that has 4 variables, but without using a matrix.

$$2x+7y+3z+u=6$$
$$3x+5y+2z+2u=4$$
$$9x+4y+z+7u=2$$

How should I proceed, I've never done a system of equations with 4 variables, and looking online I only come to solutions using the matrix.

Comment: It has infinite solutions.

Comment: You get infinite solutions. However, you can use Gaussian elimination to get three two variable equations, namely between x and u, y and u and z and u (or others according to which variables you wish to eliminate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use substitution. First, you get that $$u=6-2x-7y-3z$$ from the first equation. Now you replace it the second an third and get the new 2 equation system (it has been simplyfied):
$$x+9y+4z=8,$$
$$3x+45y+20z=40.$$
Now, do the same on the first of the above equations for $x$ to get that
$$x=8-9y-4z$$
and replacce it in the last one to get the equation (it has been simplyfied)
$$7y+2z=4.$$
Finally, you now know that $y=\frac{4-2z}{7}$. You replace now this value in $x$ equation to get its value in function of $z$ and finally the same for $u$. Now, it's finished, obtaining infinite solutions determined by the value of $z$.

Comment: Of course this is exactly what you would have done using Gaussian elimination on "the matrix", which for some reason the OP wanted to avoid.

Comment: I dont know the matrix, so thats why i want to try and avoid it, at least untill i learn it

Comment: Well, this method is in fact the first tour taught os school, and very clear without writing any Matrix. It's called substitution method. Ask me if it's not understandable.

Comment: It's clear, thank you. I have a question that isnt really related to this tho, if i have a fraction like this - $xy/x+y=2/3$ is it allowed for me to flip the fractions and rewrite it as $x+y/xy=3/2$?

Comment: @TheSlavSQuat yes, you totally can.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter how many variable there are, you do the same thing.  Eliminate $x$ from every equation but the first.  Then eliminate $y$ from the third equation.  Solve the third equation of $z$ in terms of $u$, the solve the second for $y$ in terms of $u$ and the first for $x$ in terms of $u$.  (It may happen that the third equation becomes $0=0$ so that $u$ and $z$ are both free parameters, or you may get $0=1$ o that there are no solutions at all.)

Answer (score 0):

$$2x+7y+3z+u=6$$
$$3x+5y+2z+2u=4$$
$$9x+4y+z+7u=2$$
$$  $$
$$2x+7y+3z+u=6$$
$$-x-9y-4z=-8$$
$$-5x-45y-20z=-40$$
$$  $$
$$2x+7y+3z+u=6$$
$$-x-9y-4z=-8$$
$$x+9y+4z=8$$
$$  $$
$$2x+7y+3z+u=6$$
$$x+9y+4z=8$$
$$  $$
$$-11y-5z+u=-10$$
$$x+9y+4z=8$$

so $y,z$ can be whatever you like. If they are integers, so are $x,u$